# Using old MMC snap-in on windows 2003 x64 and windows 2008 x64 with .NET 4.0 Framework

Tags: c#, unicode, mmc, mmc3

We are using the ironring MMC C# library, on win2003 32bit it's work good using .NET 1.1 framework.
we do some upgrade to the ironring MMC C# library and convert it to .NET 4.0.
it's seems to work good except that we see a corrupted text in our snap-in, i mean instead of seeing Hebrew text, some of the hebrew text we can see and other hebrew text we can't ,we see ?????? instead.we are using MMC3 format.

it's work good on my local dev machine win7 x64 untill last week when i think some windows hotfix Spoiled it.

can someone help me with this and give me a detail installation steps to install our snap-in with the ironring MMC C# library for both win2003 x64 ,win2008 x64 (i don't care about the MMC version if it 32bit or 64bit, i just want the snap-in to work on windows x64)?

does someone upgrade the ironring MMC C# library to .NET 4.0?

Thanks.

Comment: I thought MMC does not really support .NET 4.0 :-(

Comment: MMC does not officially support .NET 4.0; however, there is a workaround: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/474039/can-not-use-net-4-0-to-create-mmc-snapin